# Equations of the tangent lines of $y=x^4$ at the point $(2,0)$?

Tags: calculus

> Consider the curve $y=x^4$.
>
> $(A)$ - *The item $A$ was [asked yesterday](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1218206/25805), I put it here in case it is useful.*
>
> $(B)$ - Determine the equations of the tangent lines to the curve that pass through the point $(2,0)$.

I don't understand what I should do in this question. There is actually no tangent line to the curve that passes through $(2,0)$. I thought that it could be about translating the line tangent to the curve, but it also doesn't seems to make sense.

Comment: @DanielEscudero Oh, I get it. What is being asked is the equation of the line that passes through $(2,0)$ and touches the curve. I guess it's this.

Comment: My concern is why the word "lines"? It's supposed to be just one line.

Comment: However, you're right... $(2,0)$ is not a point of the curve. I think what you're being asked is to find a tangent line to that curve that passes through the point $(2,0)$. In fact, there will be two of those lines. (The intersection point between the line and the curve also needs to be found)

Comment: @DanielEscudero Yes. I also think it's weird to ask about *lines*, In my mind, I also think it's only one line. But he used the plural *retas* in [here](http://i.imgur.com/jWzTaEC.jpg).

Comment: One of the lines is $y=0$.

Comment: @DanielEscudero Yes! There are lines in both directions. That should explain the *lines*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no tangent line to that curve *at* $(2,0)$, but there are two tangent lines to that curve *that pass through* $(2,0)$.  It is tangent to the curve at some point $(a,a^4)$, were the slope is $4a^3$.  So
$$
4a^3 = \text{slope} = \frac{a^4-0}{a-2},
$$
whence we get
$$
4a^3(a-2) = a^4.
$$
If $a\ne0$ we can divide both sides of this by $a^3$, getting $4(a-2)=a$. It follows that $a=8/3$.  On the other hand, if $a=0$, we get another such tangent line.

Answer (score 1):

Let $f(x)=x^4$. We're going to write an equation describing the line passing through the point $(x,x^4)$ and (2, 0) that has slope $f^\prime(x)$.
$$f^\prime(x)=4x^3
\\ 0=f^\prime(x)(2-x)+f(x)=4x^3(2-x)+x^4$$
If you solve this equation you should find two lines that pass through (2, 0) and are tangent to $x^4$.